# Jquery show specific elements based on checked checkboxes

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to show only specific div's with a specific name when a checkbox with a corresponding name is checked.

I currently have the following code:

```
$(".checkbox").change(function () {
  var checkbox = $(this).val();

  if ($(".item").hasClass(checkbox)) {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
          $(".item." + checkbox).show();
      } else {
          $(".item." + checkbox).hide();
      }
  }
});
```

The above codes does the following: When I check a checkbox with the name 'industry' it will also show the div with the class '.item .industry'. When I then also check the checkbox with the name 'office' it will show all the div's with both '.industry' and '.office' as class name ('.item .industry .office).

Now I also want to add a checkbox named 'all'. This is the default state and needs to show all the divs with the class '.item'. When one of the other checkboxes is checked it needs to uncheck 'all' and show only the divs with the same name as the checked checkboxes. I also want this to work the other way around. When everything is unchecked it should automatically check all (else no div will be shown).

What I tried myself is to give all the .item divs an extra class ('.all'). The all checkbox also has the value 'all' but for some reason this does not work correctly.

Comment: Seeing your HTML would help a lot here. Also, please add the code that you attempted to write the check/uncheck all logic. At the moment your question is borderline 'write my code for me'

Comment: you can hide/show all by $(".item").each(function(){ // your code }); for other things show html code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look, its christmas and Santa brought some CODE!

HTML

```
<div>
  <label for="industry">
    Industry
    <input class="checkbox single" type="checkbox" value="industry" name="industry" id="industry" checked>
  </label>
  <label for="office">
    Office
    <input class="checkbox single" type="checkbox" value="office" name="office" id="office" checked>
  </label>
  <label for="all">
    All
    <input class="checkbox all" type="checkbox" value="all" name="all" id="all" checked>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="item industry">
  <h4>
   Industry
  </h4>
</div>
<div class="item office">
  <h4>
    Office
  </h4>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(".checkbox").change(function() {
  var $self       = $(this),
      checkboxVal = $self.val(),
      selector    = checkboxVal === "all" ? ".item" : ".item." + checkboxVal;

  // Show or hide divs based on selector, for example:
  // $(".item").show() will show all items while
  // $(".item.industry").show() will only show the industry div
  if ($self.is(":checked")) {
    $(selector).show();
  } else {
    $(selector).hide();
  }

  // This part is optional but it feels awkward without.
  // If the changed checkbox is the "all" checkbox, we want all checkboxes
  // to be checked. Vice versa if we click a single checkbox we want
  // the "all" checkbox to react accordingly
  if (checkboxVal === "all") {
    $(".checkbox.single").prop("checked", $self.is(":checked"));
  } else {
    if ($(".checkbox.single:checked").length === $(".checkbox.single").length) {
      $(".checkbox.all").prop("checked", true);
    } else {
      $(".checkbox.all").prop("checked", false);
    }
  }
});
```

[Use this fiddle to play around](https://jsfiddle.net/gbg1doo7/), but next time you should provide a little more code to prevent the "I'm not your codemonkey" feeling :)

Comment: Thank you, works perfect :). I'm sorry for the limited code I provided. I will keep your comments in mind. Will include the HTML and research I did myself the next time I ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `array` and `map`. May it help [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/7bdfyfa3/#&togetherjs=81CBf82dER)

JS:

```js
var array = $("input[type='checkbox']").map(function(){
  if($(this).val() != 'all')
  return $(this).val(); 
  else 
  return null;
  });
  
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
  var checkbox = $(this).val();
  var count = 0;
  if ($(".item").hasClass(checkbox)) {
      if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
          $(".item." + checkbox).show();
      } else {
          $(".item." + checkbox).hide();
      }
  }
  else
  {
  if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
          $("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked","checked");
  $("div").show();
      } else {
          $("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked","");
  $("div").hide();
      }
  }
  
   $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked'))
  {
  if($.inArray( $(this).val(), array ) > -1)
  {
  count++;
  }
  }
  });
  
   if(array.length == count && checkbox !='all')
  {
  $("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked","checked");
  $("div").show();
  }
  if(array.length > count)
  {
  $("input[type='checkbox'][value='all']").prop("checked","");
  }
});
```

```css
.item{
  background-color:yellow;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" value="all"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="industry"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="Company"/>
<input type="checkbox" value="mill"/>
<div class="item industry">
industry
</div>
<div class="item Company">
Company
</div>
<div class="item mill">
mill
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach using mostly jQuery methods (plus a very light sprinking of the `this.checked` DOM method):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input[value="all"]').prop('checked', true);
    $('input[value^="box-"]').prop('checked', false);
    
    $('input[value^="box-"]').change(function(){
        $('input[value="all"]').prop('checked', false);

        $('input[value^="box-"]').each(function(){ 
            var uncheckedCount = 0;
            var checkValue = $(this).val();
            $('div').hide();

            $('input[value^="box-"]').each(function(){ 
                var box = $(this).val();
                if (this.checked) {
                    $('.' + box).show();
                }

                else {
                   uncheckedCount++;
                }

                if (uncheckedCount === $('input[value^="box-"]').length) {
                    $('input[value="all"]').prop('checked', true);
                    $('div').show();
                }
            }); 
        });
    });

    $('input[value="all"]').change(function(){
        $('input[value^="box-"]').prop('checked', false);
        $('input[value="all"]').prop('checked', true);
        $('div').show();
    });
});
```

```css
div {
display: inline-block;
width:100px;
height:100px;
margin-top: 24px;
font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
line-height: 100px;
color: rgb(255,255,255);
background-color:rgb(255,0,0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" value="all" checked />All
<input type="checkbox" value="box-a" />Box A
<input type="checkbox" value="box-b" />Box B
<input type="checkbox" value="box-c" />Box C
<br />

<div class="box-a">Box A Div</div>
<div class="box-b">Box B Div</div>
<div class="box-c">Box C Div</div>
```